# Is there a way to change the partition backup parameter in Gridgain cache?

Tags: gridgain

I have below table in gridgain.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(....) WITH "template=partitioned,backups=1"
```

I would like to increase the parameter backups=1 --> backups=3. Is there a command to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the backup factor can't be changed without table re-creation.

As a workaround, you can create a new table with BACKUPS=3, copy the data from the old table to the new one, and after that drop the old table.

Comment: Is there way to set backups=3 as a global cache parameter?  It can happen that someone who is creating may forget to include "backups=3" while creating a new cache. I would like to enforce BACKUPS=3 for all the new caches that are being created.